# How to join multiple lines of filenames into one with custom delimiter

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell, parsing

How do I join the result of `ls -1` into a single line and [delimit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter) it with whatever I want?

Answer (score 891, accepted):

`paste -s -d` joins lines with a delimiter (e.g. `","`), and does not leave a trailing delimiter:

```
ls -1 | paste -sd "," -
```

Comment: Just as a note, the version of paste I tried requires a "-" argument at the end to tell it to read from STDIN.  e.g. `ls -1 | paste -s -d ":" -`  Not sure if that's universal with all versions of paste

Comment: this one is better because it allows empty delimiter :)

Comment: Note `paste` gets `-` (standard input) as default, at least on my `paste (GNU coreutils) 8.22`.

Comment: i just upvoted it, this is and now it has the same votes as the selected answer.
THIS IS THE ANSWER. no trailing delimeter

Comment: The empty delimiter can be specified using `"\0"`, so `paste -sd "\0" -` worked for me!

Comment: @BradParks, what's wrong with just `paste -sd "" -`?

Comment: @iururu not if it's empty 

Comment: How can I do it with no delimiter?

Comment: This way, the delimiter can only be a single character.

Answer (score 422):

> **EDIT**: Simply "**ls -m**" If you want your delimiter to be a comma

Ah, the power and simplicity !

```
ls -1 | tr '\n' ','
```

Change the comma "**,**" to whatever you want.  Note that this includes a "trailing comma" (for lists that end with a newline)

Comment: +1, but a more elaborate version should handle last \n differently

Comment: If the file name contains a `\n` in it, this will replace that too.

Comment: @unicornaddict you can use -b or -q for ls to handle strange cases like you mention.

Comment: @mouviciel that would be a nice touch.

Comment: @mouviciel: You can just append a "\n" at the end, with say, `ls -1 | tr "\\n" ","; echo`

Comment: @ShreevatsaR:  he means to not append a trailing "," I believe.  like so `ls -1 | tr "\\n" "," | sed 's/\(.*\),/\1/'`

Comment: @Chris: your `sed` could be a little more efficient with the end-marker character:
`ls -1 | tr "\\n" "," | sed 's/,$//'; echo ''`

Comment: Or just `ls -1 | tr '\n' ,`

Comment: Can I use two commas as the delimiter. It seems it always show only one.

Comment: @ElgsQianChen I suppose you can. Add another comma in the command.  Have you tried it?

Comment: `ls | paste -sd, -` is the best way to do it - no need to worry about the trailing comma.  No need for `-1` in `ls` because it is implied when the output is not going to the terminal.

Comment: Using `sed` after `tr` seems just to remove last symbol seems unreasonable.

I go with `ls -1 | tr '\n' ',' | head -c -1`

Comment: This almost works, but as many mentioned, leaves the trailing comma. What worked for me in keeping with the simplicity: `ls -1 | xargs | tr " " ","`

Answer (score 40):

This replaces the last comma with a newline:

```
ls -1 | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$/\n/'
```

`ls -m` includes newlines at the screen-width character (80th for example).

Mostly Bash (only `ls` is external):

```
saveIFS=$IFS; IFS=$'\n'
files=($(ls -1))
IFS=,
list=${files[*]}
IFS=$saveIFS
```

Using `readarray` (aka `mapfile`) in Bash 4:

```
readarray -t files < <(ls -1)
saveIFS=$IFS
IFS=,
list=${files[*]}
IFS=$saveIFS
```

Thanks to gniourf_gniourf for the suggestions.

Comment: This will not take care of files with white spaces in the name. Try this one: dir=/tmp/testdir; rm -rf $dir && mkdir $dir && cd /$dir && touch "this is a file" this_is_another_file && ls -1 && files=($(ls -1)) && list=${files[@]/%/,} && list=${list%*,} && echo $list

Comment: @dimir: Many of the answers to this question suffer from this problem. I have edited my answer to allow for filenames with tabs or spaces, but not newlines.

Comment: Your bash version suffers from pathname expansions too. To build an array from lines, please consider using `mapfile` (Bash ≥4) as: `mapfile -t files < <(ls -1)`. No need to fiddle with `IFS`. And it's shorter too.

Comment: And when you have your array, you can use `IFS` to join the fields: `saveIFS=$IFS; IFS=,; list=${files[*]}; IFS=$saveIFS`. Or use another method if you want a separator with more that one character.

Comment: Also, your concatenation `list=${files[@]/%/,}` will not quite work as expected, as you'll also get the first character of `IFS` after the commas (very likely a space). Sorry for the many comments, but there are a few things to fix here!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: I have included your suggestions in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: A simple `files=(*)` will work fine. Also, a delayed evaluation of `*` will avoid playing around with IFS: `IFS=, command eval 'list=${files[*]}'; echo "<$list>"`. Of course, `IFS=, command eval echo '"${files[*]}"'` is shorter, but doesn't set `$list` variable string.

Comment: Of course, expansion of `*` works with only one character.

Answer (score 35):

I think this one is awesome

```
ls -1 | awk 'ORS=","'
```

ORS is the "output record separator" so now your lines will be joined with a comma.

Comment: This does not exclude the trailing delimiter.

Comment: This is especially awesome due to handling multi-character record separators (e.g., `" OR "`)

Answer (score 19):

Parsing `ls` in general [is not advised](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/21471), so alternative better way is to use `find`, for example:

```
find . -type f -print0 | tr '\0' ','
```

Or by using `find` and `paste`:

```
find . -type f | paste -d, -s
```

For general joining multiple lines (not related to file system), check: [Concise and portable “join” on the Unix command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8522851/55075).

Comment: While true, the other examples are general to *any* list that you want to combine into one line.

Answer (score 15):

The combination of setting `IFS` and use of `"$*"` can do what you want. I'm using a subshell so I don't interfere with this shell's $IFS

```
(set -- *; IFS=,; echo "$*")
```

To capture the output,

```
output=$(set -- *; IFS=,; echo "$*")
```

Comment: Do you have some more information regarding how `set` works? Looks a bit like voodoo to me. shallow look through `man set` didn't net me much information either.

Comment: If you give `set` a bunch of arguments but no options, it sets the positional parameters ($1, $2, ...). `--` is there to protect `set` in  case the first argument (or filename in this case) happens to start with a dash. See the description of the `--` option in `help set`. I find the positional parameters a convenient way to handle a list of things. I could also have implemented this with an array: `output=$( files=(*); IFS=,; echo "${files[*]}" )`

Comment: This is great since it doesn't require executing any additional programs and it works with file names that contain spaces or even newlines.

Comment: @EhteshChoudhury As `type set` will tell you, `set is a shell builtin`. So, `man set` will not help, but `help set` will do. Answer: "--  Assign any remaining arguments to the positional parameters."

Comment: After a `set -- *`. Delaying expansion of `*` one level you may get the correct output without the need of a sub shell: `IFS=',' eval echo '"$*"'`. Of course that will change the positional parameters.

Answer (score 12):

Adding on top of majkinetor's answer, here is the way of removing trailing delimiter(since I cannot just comment under his answer yet):

```
ls -1 | awk 'ORS=","' | head -c -1
```

Just remove as many trailing bytes as your delimiter counts for.

I like this approach because I can use multi character delimiters + other benefits of `awk`:

```
ls -1 | awk 'ORS=", "' | head -c -2
```

**EDIT**

As Peter has noticed, negative byte count is not supported in native MacOS version of head. This however can be easily fixed.

First, install `coreutils`. "The GNU Core Utilities are the basic file, shell and text manipulation utilities of the GNU operating system."

```
brew install coreutils
```

Commands also provided by MacOS are installed with the prefix "g". For example `gls`.

Once you have done this you can use `ghead` which has negative byte count, or better, make alias:

```
alias head="ghead"
```

Comment: Note: negative byte counts are only supported on certain versions of head, so this won't work on e.g. macos.

Comment: Thanks, for pointing that out. I have added a workaround for MacOS.

Answer (score 9):

Don't reinvent the wheel.

```
ls -m
```

It does exactly that.

Comment: The OP wanted any delimiter so you would still need a tr to convert the commas. It also adds a space after the commas i.e.
file1, file2, file3

Comment: so using `ls -m` and `tr` to remove the space after the comma you would do `ls -m | tr -d ' '`

Comment: that use of tr will delete spaces inside filenames. better to use `sed 's/, /,/g`

Answer (score 8):

just bash

```
mystring=$(printf "%s|" *)
echo ${mystring%|}
```

Comment: Slightly more efficient would be to use "printf -v mystring "%s|" *" - that avoids a fork for the $()

Comment: But notably doesn't chomp the trailing `|`, @camh.

Comment: Well, just `bash` and gnu coreutils `printf`

Comment: @camh But `printf -v` will work only in bash, while the presented answer works on many shell types.

Comment: @Christopher Yes, that will remove the trailing `|`, provided that both lines are used: `printf -v mystring "%s|" * ; echo ${mystring%|}`.

Comment: Quoting the echoed variable `${mystring%|}` seems like a good idea, though.

Comment: @sorontar The question is tagged "bash" and the answer my comment is on says "just bash". So why would I avoid bash?

Answer (score 8):

This command is for the PERL fans :

```
ls -1 | perl -l40pe0
```

Here 40 is the octal ascii code for space.

-p will process line by line and print

-l will take care of replacing the trailing \n with the ascii character we provide.

-e is to inform PERL we are doing command line execution.

0 means that there is actually no command to execute.

perl -e0 is same as perl -e ' '

Answer (score 6):

To avoid potential newline confusion for tr we could add the -b flag to ls:

```
ls -1b | tr '\n' ';'
```

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the answers already exist.

If you want
`a, b, c` format, use `ls -m` ( [Tulains Córdova’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16024075/766330))

Or if you want `a b c` format, use `ls | xargs` (simpified version of [Chris J’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2764101/766330))

Or if you want any other delimiter like `|`, use `ls | paste -sd'|'` (application of [Artem’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6539865/766330))

Answer (score 6):

The sed way,

```
sed -e ':a; N; $!ba; s/\n/,/g'
  # :a         # label called 'a'
  # N          # append next line into Pattern Space (see info sed)
  # $!ba       # if it's the last line ($) do not (!) jump to (b) label :a (a) - break loop
  # s/\n/,/g   # any substitution you want
```

*Note*:

This is linear in complexity, substituting only once after all lines are appended into sed's Pattern Space.

@AnandRajaseka's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2764101/4399947), and some other similar answers, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8524160/4399947), are O(n²), because sed has to do substitute every time a new line is appended into the Pattern Space.

To compare,

```
seq 1 100000 | sed ':a; N; $!ba; s/\n/,/g' | head -c 80
  # linear, in less than 0.1s
seq 1 100000 | sed ':a; /$/N; s/\n/,/; ta' | head -c 80
  # quadratic, hung
```

Answer (score 5):

```
sed -e :a -e '/$/N; s/\n/\\n/; ta' [filename]
```

Explanation:

`-e` - denotes a command to be executed
   `:a` - is a label
   `/$/N` - defines the scope of the match for the current and the (N)ext line
   `s/\n/\\n/;` - replaces all EOL with `\n`
   `ta;` - goto label a if the match is successful

Taken from [my blog](http://anandsekar.github.io/joining-all-lines-in-a-file-using-sed/).

Answer (score 4):

If you version of xargs supports the -d flag then this should work

```
ls  | xargs -d, -L 1 echo
```

-d is the delimiter flag

If you do not have -d, then you can try the following

```
ls | xargs -I {} echo {}, | xargs echo
```

The first xargs allows you to specify your delimiter which is a comma in this example.

Comment: `-d` specifies the input delimiter with GNU xargs, so will not work. The second example exhibits the same issue as other solutions here of a stray delimiter at the end.

Answer (score 2):

`ls` produces one column output when connected to a pipe, so the `-1` is redundant.

Here's another perl answer using the builtin `join` function which doesn't leave a trailing delimiter:

```
ls | perl -F'\n' -0777 -anE 'say join ",", @F'
```

The obscure `-0777` makes perl read all the input before running the program.

*sed alternative that doesn't leave a trailing delimiter*

```
ls | sed '$!s/$/,/' | tr -d '\n'
```

Answer (score 2):

Python answer above is interesting, but the own language can even make the output nice:

> ls -1 | python -c "import sys; print(sys.stdin.read().splitlines())"

Comment: I can't believe a Python oneliner is the best way I can find for a multicharacter delimiter... but it is: `python -c "import sys; print(' | '.join(sys.stdin.read().splitlines()))"`. POSIX failed me again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
ls -1 | perl -pe 's/\n$/some_delimiter/'
```

Comment: This does not exclude the trailing delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

If Python3 is your cup of tea, you can do this (but please explain why you would?):

```
ls -1 | python -c "import sys; print(','.join(sys.stdin.read().splitlines()))"
```

Comment: I don't know why the OP wants to do it, but I know why I need to do it: in order to copy all the filenames separated by a space to use them as parameters for rubocop, eslint, stylelint, haml-lint, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`ls` has the option `-m` to delimit the output with `", "` a comma and a space.

```
ls -m | tr -d ' ' | tr ',' ';'
```

piping this result to `tr` to remove either the space or the comma will allow you to pipe the result again to `tr` to replace the delimiter.

in my example i replace the delimiter `,` with the delimiter `;`

replace `;` with whatever **one character delimiter** you prefer since tr only accounts for the first character in the strings you pass in as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use chomp to merge multiple line in single line:

perl -e 'while (<>) { if (/\$/ ) { chomp; } print ;}' bad0 >test

put line break condition in if statement.It can be special character or any delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Quick Perl version with trailing slash handling:

```
ls -1 | perl -E 'say join ", ", map {chomp; $_} <>'
```

To explain:

- perl -E: execute Perl with features supports (say, ...)
- say: print with a carrier return
- join ", ", ARRAY_HERE: join an array with ", "
- map {chomp; $_} ROWS: remove from each line the carrier return and return the result
- <>: stdin, each line is a ROW, coupling with a map it will create an array of each ROW

Comment: Works as it should.