# Concise and portable "join" on the Unix command-line

Tags: shell, unix

How can I join multiple lines into one line, with a separator where the new-line characters were, and avoiding a trailing separator and, optionally, ignoring empty lines?

Example. Consider a text file, `foo.txt`, with three lines:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

The desired output is:

```
foo,bar,baz
```

The command I'm using now:

```
tr '\n' ',' <foo.txt |sed 's/,$//g'
```

Ideally it would be something like this:

```
cat foo.txt |join ,
```

What's:

1. the most portable, concise, readable way.
2. the most concise way using non-standard unix tools.

Of course I could write something, or just use an alias. But I'm interested to know the options.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Joining multiple lines into one with bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764051/joining-multiple-lines-into-one-with-bash)

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Perhaps a little surprisingly, `paste` is a good way to do this:

```
paste -s -d","
```

This won't deal with the empty lines you mentioned. For that, pipe your text through `grep`, first:

```
grep -v '^$' | paste -s -d"," -
```

Comment: @codaddict Nor I, but I must admit that I don't find it intuitive at all - I always need to check the man pages for this. I'm definitely curious to see what others suggest.

Comment: There are other ways, but none nicer (and the fun ones are a bit bashy).

Comment: It doesn't seem to ignore empty lines but this is still very nice and works for my use-case. Thanks!

Comment: @butt Sorry, I'd missed the point about the empty lines, and just duplicated what your pipeline did. See the revisions.

Comment: For enhanced portability, consider adding `-` at the end of the `paste` command whenever it's expected to read from `stdin`.  (Some versions of `paste`, such BSD's, won't read from `stdin` unless `-` is explicitly passed to it.)

Comment: @kjo and POSIX mandates it. Editing the post now. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/paste.htm

Comment: The command name may not be that intuitive, but it does exactly what's needed here. Man page starts with `paste -- merge corresponding or subsequent lines of files`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about `paste`! I noticed it allows only single-character delimiters, and it's `\t` by default. To accomplish longer delimiters (e.g. `, `): `cat foo.txt | paste -s | sed 's/\t/, /g'`

Comment: `paste -sd,` to be more concise.  Don't need the double quotes around `,`.

Answer (score 14):

This `sed` one-line should work -

`sed -e :a -e 'N;s/\n/,/;ba' file`

**Test:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
foo
bar
baz

[jaypal:~/Temp] sed -e :a -e 'N;s/\n/,/;ba' file
foo,bar,baz
```

To handle empty lines, you can remove the empty lines and pipe it to the above one-liner.

```
sed -e '/^$/d' file | sed -e :a -e 'N;s/\n/,/;ba'
```

Comment: An explanation would be nice!

Comment: It's more clear to combine two -e expression into one, `sed -e ':a; N; s/\n/,/; ba'`. But this is still an O(n²) method, because sed will do some substitution every time a new line added. `sed -e ':a; N; $!ba; s/\n/,/g'` is linear, substituting only once after all lines are appended into sed's Pattern Space. `$!ba` means "if it's the last line ($) do not (!) jump to (b) label :a (a), break the loop"

Answer (score 10):

How about to use xargs?

for your case

```
$ cat foo.txt | sed 's/$/, /' | xargs
```

Be careful about the limit length of input of xargs command. (This means very long input file cannot be handled by this.)

Comment: I found the `-L`  flag on xargs helpful `-L 50` will 50 items per line.

Answer (score 6):

Perl:

```
cat data.txt | perl -pe 'if(!eof){chomp;$_.=","}'
```

or yet shorter and faster, surprisingly:

```
cat data.txt | perl -pe 'if(!eof){s/\n/,/}'
```

or, if you want:

```
cat data.txt | perl -pe 's/\n/,/ unless eof'
```

Comment: The nice thing about this is you can use any string instead of just a simple comma. The accepted answer is less versatile. I especially like the final iteration, although I would have written it like: `perl -pe 's/\n/,/ unless eof' data.txt`  (no need for the spurious cat).

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun, here's an all-builtins solution

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a data < foo.txt ; ( IFS=, ; echo "${data[*]}" ; )
```

You can use `printf` instead of `echo` if the trailing newline is a problem.

This works by setting `IFS`, the delimiters that `read` will split on, to just newline and not other whitespace, then telling `read` to not stop reading until it reaches a `nul`, instead of the newline it usually uses, and to add each item read into the array (`-a`) data. Then, in a subshell so as not to clobber the `IFS` of the interactive shell, we set `IFS` to `,` and expand the array with `*`, which delimits each item in the array with the first character in `IFS`

Comment: interesting, however portability is not excellent, since there's no `-d` option in pure `sh` shell `read` command.

Comment: @mykhal: True. However, `bash` can be found on many systems, so it has some utility. If you want portability arrays are probably out, too, otherwise you could simply use a `while` loop to work around the lack of `-d`. For a proper, portable all-builtins version you'd want something like `c= ; while IFS= read -r d ; do if ! [ -z "$d" ] ; then printf "$c$d" ; fi c=, ; done < foo.txt` but it still fails for `read` that knows `-r`, but that could be omitted, and assumes a builtin `printf`, so `echo` is probably better there if efficiency is important. Still, the accepted answer is much better!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to accomplish something similar, printing a comma-separated list of fields from a file, and was happy with piping STDOUT to `xargs` and `ruby`, like so:

```
cat data.txt | cut -f 16 -d ' ' | grep -o "\d\+" | xargs ruby -e "puts ARGV.join(', ')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to join the lines with space in-place using `ex` (also ignoring blank lines), use:

```
ex +%j -cwq foo.txt
```

If you want to print the results to the standard output, try:

```
ex +%j +%p -scq! foo.txt
```

To join lines without spaces, use `+%j!` instead of `+%j`.

To use different delimiter, it's a bit more tricky:

```
ex +"g/^$/d" +"%s/\n/_/e" +%p -scq! foo.txt
```

where `g/^$/d` (or `v/\S/d`) removes blank lines and `s/\n/_/` is substitution which basically works the same as using `sed`, but for all lines (`%`). When parsing is done, print the buffer (`%p`). And finally `-cq!` executing vi `q!` command, which basically quits without saving (`-s` is to silence the output).

Please note that `ex` is equivalent to `vi -e`.

This method is quite portable as most of the Linux/Unix are shipped with `ex`/`vi` by default. And it's more compatible than using `sed` where in-place parameter (`-i`) is not standard extension and utility it-self is more stream oriented, therefore it's not so portable.

Answer (score 0):

I had a log file where some data was broken into multiple lines.  When this occurred, the last character of the first line was the semi-colon (;).  I joined these lines by using the following commands:

```
for LINE in 'cat $FILE | tr -s " " "|"'
do
    if [ $(echo $LINE | egrep ";$") ]
    then
        echo "$LINE\c" | tr -s "|" " " >> $MYFILE
    else
        echo "$LINE" | tr -s "|" " " >> $MYFILE
    fi
done
```

The result is a file where lines that were split in the log file were one line in my new file.

Answer (score 0):

POSIX shell:

```
( set -- $(cat foo.txt) ; IFS=+ ; printf '%s\n' "$*" )
```

Answer (score -1):

My answer is:

```
awk '{printf "%s", ","$0}' foo.txt
```

`printf` is enough. We don't need `-F"\n"` to change field separator.

Comment: This adds a spurious comma at the beginning of the output. -1 for not testing.