# moving every second row to a new column with awk

Tags: awk

Here is another noob question. I have a file like this

```
John
30
Mike
0.0786268
Tyson
0.114889
Gabriel
0.176072
Fiona
0.101895
```

I need to shift every second row to a new column so it should look like this

```
John   30
Mike   0.0786268
Tyson  0.114889
Gabriel 0.176072
Fiona   0.101895
```

I just now that `awk 'NR%2==0'` will print every second row, could somebody suggest me how to shift them to a new column as above.  Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: Related, but not awk specific: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522851/concise-and-portable-join-on-the-unix-command-line

Answer (score 11):

```
awk '{printf "%s%s",$0,(NR%2?FS:RS)}' file
```

---

Explanation:

- `printf` will not include a new line character at the end of line (unlike `print`)
- `(NR%2?FS:RS)` decides new line (RS) or  field seperator (FS) based on `NR%2`

If your colmns should be seperated by `\t`

```
awk '{printf "%s%s",$0,NR%2?"\t":RS}'
```

Comment: This is a most excellent and elegant illustration of AWK.  No other solution comes close.

Comment: This helped me. Thanks @ed-Morton

Answer (score 10):

xargs could do it, the command line is really short:

```
xargs -n2 < file
```

Comment: I know it's not awk, but I love this answer.  Clever!

Answer (score 1):

One way is:

```
awk '{ printf("%-10s ",$0); if(NR%2==0) printf("\n");}' file
```

[**See it**](http://ideone.com/sLsnG5)

Comment: Thank you for the one liner, it really works fine. I have just started learning awk and if I could ask you a bit more, I guess  printf("%-10s ",$0)  will print every thing in a line, but I could not understand after this. Thanks again.

Comment: `printf` prints without a newline and `%s` is the format specification for a string. `%-10s` will pad with spaces to a length of 10, left justified, or truncate a longer string. I would actually `printf("%s ", $0)` instead, with a space after %s, alternatively a tab character, `\t`.

Comment: printf is a builtin, not a function, so the () don't do what you think they do, the trailing semi-colon is superflous, and the way to print a newline is `print ""`.

Answer (score 1):

sed is better to do this than awk:

```
sed 'N;s/\n/ /g' yourfile
```

also in awk:

```
awk '{if(NR%2!=0){p=""}else{p="\n"};printf $0" "p}' your_file
```

also check another solution [here](http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2012/12/join-every-two-lines-in-file.html)

Comment: sed is NOT better to do this than awk as that is NOT even close to how you would do it in awk.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to use `sed` like this:

```
sed 'N;s/\n/ /' file
```

However, this won't nicely format your data. You could pipe it into `column -t`:

```
< file sed 'N;s/\n/ /' | column -t
```

But this seems unnecessary. It would be better to use `paste` like this:

```
paste - - < file
```

Results:

```
John    30
Mike    0.0786268
Tyson   0.114889
Gabriel 0.176072
Fiona   0.101895
```

Answer (score 1):

```
paste - - < file > newfile
```

paste uses tab as a separator by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR%2{s=$0; next} {print s, $0}' file
```

or using [default action](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Very-Simple.html)

```
awk 'NR%2{s=$0; next} {$0=s" "$0}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` solution, more elegant than the most upvoted one IMO (shorter at least) :

```
$ awk 'ORS=NR%2?FS:RS' file
John 30
Mike 0.0786268
Tyson 0.114889
Gabriel 0.176072
Fiona 0.101895
```