# How to stop a for instance bash script

Tags: json, bash, shell, loops, unix

I had this files

```
$img=1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg,4.jpg,5.jpg,6.jpg,7.jpg
```

Here is my code

```
# Split on the comma, and create an array
 IFS=',' read -ra images <<< "$timg"
# Start the JSON
echo "\"pictures\":["

# loop through the images, and output the JSON
# keep track of the index of output items
counter=1
for image in "${images[@]}"
do
    echo -n "    {\"source\":\"$image\"}"
    # Add a comma unless it is the last element in the array
    if [ $counter -lt ${#images[@]} ]
    then
        echo ","
    else
        echo ""
    fi
    (( counter = counter + 1 ))
done

# Close the JSON
echo "]}"
```

The result is

```
{"source":"1.jpg"},
{"source":"2.jpg"},
{"source":"3.jpg"},
{"source":"4.jpg"},
{"source":"5.jpg"},
{"source":"6.jpg"},
{"source":"7.jpg"}
```

I want to  give to for comand only read x numbers and stop.
Its  Posible ? Thx
Example i want to run only first 5
The result desire is :

```
{"source":"1.jpg"},
{"source":"2.jpg"},
{"source":"3.jpg"},
{"source":"4.jpg"},
{"source":"5.jpg"}
```

Comment: Don't create JSON by hand like that. Install the `jq` utility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a slice of the array, and loop over that.

```
images=("${images[0]:0:5}")
```

See [How to slice an array in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335815/how-to-slice-an-array-in-bash)

Comment: Thx is the most beatiful answer i like :)

Answer (score 3):

This is almost trivial using `jq`:

```
$ img=1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg,4.jpg,5.jpg,6.jpg,7.jpg
$ echo "$img" | jq -R --argjson n 5 'split(",")[:$n] | {pictures: map({source: .})}'
{
  "pictures": [
    {
      "source": "1.jpg"
    },
    {
      "source": "2.jpg"
    },
    {
      "source": "3.jpg"
    },
    {
      "source": "4.jpg"
    },
    {
      "source": "5.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

timg='image1.png,image2.png,image3.png,image4.png,image5.png,image6.png'

# Split on the comma, and create an array
IFS=',' read -ra images <<< "$timg"

# Start the JSON
echo '{ "pictures": ['

for ((i=0; i<5 && i<${#images[@]}; i++)); do
  printf '  { "source": "%s" }\n' "${images[i]}"
done | paste -sd ","

echo ']}'
```

Output:

```
{ "pictures": [
  { "source": "image1.png" },  { "source": "image2.png" },  { "source": "image3.png" },  { "source": "image4.png" },  { "source": "image5.png" }
]}
```

Notes:

- Since this shell script uses arrays, it's essential that it starts with `#!/bin/bash`, otherwise it *could* be run by a POSIX shell.
- Consider using single quotes so you don't have to escape double quotes as often (e.g. on the `echo`s that involved JSON)
- See `bash(1)` for more info on this more C-like form of a `for`-loop.
- `${#images[@]}` evaluates to the number of elements in the `images` array.
- The entire `for`-condition will ensure that the loop terminates when we're either at the end of the `images` array or have emitted `5` objects.  Consider making a `5` a variable to help make the code a little more self documenting.
- `printf` is a handy way to emit a string that includes double quotes, but needs values to be injected.
- `paste -sd ","` will effectively [join the lines on its standard input by the provided delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522851/concise-and-portable-join-on-the-unix-command-line).  This helps simplify the logic for adding commas.

Comment: Nice one! Thx =)