# How to replace the nth column/field in a comma-separated string using sed/awk?

Tags: bash, replace, sed, awk, csv

assume I have a string

```
"1,2,3,4"
```

Now I want to replace, e.g. the 3rd field of the string by some different value.

```
"1,2,NEW,4"
```

I managed to do this with the following command:

```
echo "1,2,3,4" | awk -F, -v OFS=, '{$3="NEW"; print }'
```

Now the index for the column to be replaced should be passed as a variable. So in this case

```
index=3
```

How can I pass this to awk? Because this won't work:

```
echo "1,2,3,4" | awk -F, -v OFS=, '{$index="NEW"; print }'
echo "1,2,3,4" | awk -F, -v OFS=, '{$($index)="NEW"; print }'
echo "1,2,3,4" | awk -F, -v OFS=, '{\$$index="NEW"; print }'
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have the shell interpolate the index in the awk program:

```
echo "1,2,3,4" | awk -F, -v OFS=, '{$'$index'="NEW"; print }'
```

Note how the originally single quoted awk program is split in three parts, a single quoted beginning '{$', the interpolated index value, followed by the single quoted remainder of the program.

Comment: You can use `-v var=value` to define a variable inside awk through its command line and then use `$var`. So this text substitution hack is not needed.

Answer (score 7):

This might work for you:

```
index=3 
echo "1,2,3,4" | awk -F, -v OFS=, -v INDEX=$index '{$INDEX="NEW"; print }'
```

or:

```
index=3 
echo "1,2,3,4" | sed 's/[^,]*/NEW/'$index
```

Comment: how is it done if "NEW" is assigned to a variable? this is not working: `sed 's/[^,]*/$var/'$index`

Comment: @dcdum2018 notice the double quotes.

Comment: i tried these: `echo $line | awk -F, -v OFS=, -v INDEX=$index '{$INDEX="$var"; print}'` and
`echo $line | sed 's/[^,]*/$var/'$index`, but both are literally replacing with `$var`

Comment: @dcdum2018 single quotes prevents interpolation therefore either use double quotes or put the shell variable outside of the single quotes e.g. `sed "s/[^,]*/$var/$index" file1` or `sed 's/[^,]*/'$var'/'$index file`

Comment: it worked well! thank you! if it isn't much, could you please have a look on my question here? :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69751857/remove-last-character-using-for-loop

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `sed`uctive way to break the `awk`wardness:

```
$ echo "1,2,3,4" | sed 's/,/\n/g' | sed -e $index's/.*/NEW/'
```

This is easily extendable to multiple indexes just by adding another `-e $newindex's/.*/NEWNEW/'`

Comment: How can I convert the newlines back to a comma-separated list? I tried sed 's/\n/,/g' but that won't work?

Comment: @PeterMeier, I think it doesn't work because `sed` treats lines separately now, not as a whole text. Having looked at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6539865/1258041), I suggest piping the output to `paste -sd ','` like this: `echo "1,2,3,4" | sed 's/,/\n/g' | sed -e $index's/.*/NEW/' | paste -sd ','`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# This should be faster than awk or sed.
str="1,2,3,4"
IFS=','
read -a f <<< "$str"
f[2]='NEW'
printf "${f[*]}"
```

Answer (score -1):

With plain awk (I.E. Not gawk etc) I believe you'll have to use `split( string, array, [fieldsep] );` change the array entry of choice and then join them back together with `sprintf` or similar in a loop.

gawk allows you to have a variable as a field name, $index in your example.  See [here.](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Nonconstant-Fields)

gawk is usually the default awk on Linux, so change your invocation to gawk "script" and see if it works.