# Sorting a single column of a file without disturbing the others columns

Tags: unix, columnsorting

I have a file trial.txt in which I want to sort its fourth column only without changing the order of the other colums .
My file contents is like this.

```
A user 9 12 ab    
B user 2 9 cd    
C user 5 13 da
```

I want my output to look like this

```
A user 9 13 ab    
B user 2  12 cd    
C user 5  9 da
```

I had tried this.

```
sort -k 4 trial.txt
```

but it is not giving the output as expected.

Answer (score 0):

use:
`sort -k4 -n -s trial.txt`
Apart from the `k` option, it is advised you use `-n` for comparing numbers, the `-s` option suppresses the last resort comparison. check the manual for more info.
Also, your required output is showing descending order, in case use `-r` option to reverse the sorting pattern.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but yet this is still not working. As ,I am using -n for comparing the numbers, but also not working and still giving the same output as above. I want to do it with sed or with awk. As ,alone sort cannot do this. please have a look on this using some sed and awk commands  . Help will be really appreciated.

Comment: I am sorry I misread your question, I have sorted all the lines on the basis of 4th column.

Comment: Thats fine Akash. As i am stucked on the logic of this question.Now i think ,it can be done by using awk command .I am confused in how to use the array and loop for this.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for giving a wrong interpretation of the question. So here is the final answer. It's simple:

1. First use `awk` to get the third column of the file trial.txt and save it in a temporary file.
2. Sort this temporary file.
3. Read every line from the trial.txt and temporary file simultaneously. To do this read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82541/loop-through-the-lines-of-two-files-in-parallel. Then from each input of the line from trial.txt replace its 4th column using awk with the line input from the temporary file. To do this take help from [How to replace the nth column/field in a comma-separated string using sed/awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838160/how-to-replace-the-nth-column-field-in-a-comma-separated-string-using-sed-awk). Store this in a new file and delete temp after this. Done!