# Remove last character using for loop

Tags: for-loop, unix, scripting, trim

I have an input that needs to be queried but if query returns null, the last character from the input should be removed, then it will be used for query again until a value is fetched from the table.

input: `123456`

query: `select col1 from table where input='123456';` --null output

input: `12345`

query: `select col1 from table where input='12345';` --null output

input: `1234`

query: `select col1 from table where input='1234';` --null output

input: `123`

query: `select col1 from table where input='123';` --null output

input: `12`

query: `select col1 from table where input='12';` --NOT null output

return output: `col1 value`

```
method () {
export input=$1
echo "input : "$input

for (i++, input.length(), i++ ){ #for entire length of input
   methodForQuery "$input" #deduct last character for every iteration
   echo "output : "$output   
   
   if [ -z "$output" ]
   then
      continue #if output is null, deduct last character
               #but if last one character still returns null, set output as null
   else
      break #if output is not null, break loop and return $output
   fi
}

echo "output : " $output
}

methodForQuery (){
   output=#sqlplus... 
   select col1 from table where input='$input' and rownum < 2;
}
```

Comment: You don't need a loop for that; `${input%?}` returns the value of `$input` with the last character removed.

Answer (score 0):

done by using the ff:

```
method () {
export input=$1
echo "input : "$input
j="$input"

for (( i=1, j=0 ; i<=$length ; i++, j=j+1)); do
   len=$(echo "$((length-$j))")
   newinp=$(echo ${input:0:$len})
   methodForQuery "$newinp"
   echo "output : "$output  
   
   if [ -z "$output" ]
   then
      continue 
   else
      break 
   fi
}

echo "output : " $output
}

methodForQuery (){
   output=#sqlplus... 
   select col1 from table where input='$input' and rownum < 2;
}
```