# How can I save all filenames in a directory to a text file in bash?

Tags: file, bash, shell, unix, ls

I have a directory with millions of files.  I've just learned millions are orphaned and I need to unlink them.  I'd like to start with an array of all files in a single text file (csv ideally).  Can you help?

I was going to do an `ls` and just save the terminal output to a file, but I figure there's a more elegant way.

How can I make something like `ls > log.csv` end up looking like

`file1.txt,file2.txt, ... fileN.txt`?

Comment: This one looks similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764051/joining-multiple-lines-into-one-with-bash

Comment: @leafei, wow. That's awesome. Trying this now: `ls -1 | tr "\\n" "," > log.csv`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
printf '%s\n' *.txt | paste -sd "," - > log.csv
```

or

```
printf '%s,' *.txt > log.csv
```

or

```
printf '"%s",' *.txt > log.csv
```

if you have special characters like spaces in filenames.