# How to concatenate multiple lines of output to one line?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep, tr

If I run the command `cat file | grep pattern`, I get many lines of output. How do you concatenate all lines into one line, effectively replacing each `"\n"` with `"\" "` (end with `"` followed by space)?

`cat file | grep pattern | xargs sed s/\n/ /g` 
isn't working for me.

Comment: By the way: (1) you need to put your `sed` script in single-quotes so that Bash doesn't mess with it (since `sed s/\n/ /g` calls `sed` with two arguments, namely `s/n/` and `/g`); (2) since you want the output of `cat file | grep pattern` to be the *input* to `sed`, not the *arguments* to `sed`, you need to eliminate `xargs`; and (3) there's no need for `cat` here, since `grep` can take a filename as its second argument. So, you should have tried `grep pattern file | sed 's/\n/ /g'`. (In this case it wouldn't have worked, for reasons given at the above link, but now you know for the future.)

Comment: similar to "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764051/how-to-join-multiple-lines-of-file-names-into-one-with-custom-delimiter"

Comment: Question with 68 votes (140k views) duplicated with post which has only 1 vote (12k views)? This isn't right.

Comment: See: [Should I flag a question as duplicate if it has received better answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251938/55075)

Answer (score 382, accepted):

Use `tr '\n' ' '` to translate all newline characters to spaces:

```
$ grep pattern file | tr '\n' ' '
```

Note: `grep` reads files, `cat` concatenates files. Don't `cat file | grep`!

**Edit:**

`tr` can only handle single character translations. You could use `awk` to change the output record separator like:

```
$ grep pattern file | awk '{print}' ORS='" '
```

This would transform:

```
one
two 
three
```

to:

```
one" two" three"
```

Comment: You endup with an undesired space at the end with this approach.

Comment: You need to add `echo ""` at the end to add new line before prompt text.

Comment: This works out nicely, however I don't want the separator to show up on the very last entry. Example, per your `"`, it shows up like `one" two" three"`, however I'd want it to show up like `one" two" three`. Note the last three doesn't have a parenthesis. Any ideas?

Comment: @oink you could pipe the results into `sed '$s/..$//'` to delete the last 2 characters on the last line.

Comment: If you want to replace newlines with nothing, you need to use the `--delete` option as the default expects two arguments. e.g. `tr --delete '\n'`.

Answer (score 120):

In bash `echo` without quotes remove carriage returns, tabs and multiple spaces

```
echo $(cat file)
```

Comment: Severely underrated answer here, this is really simple and works like a charm, with a trailing newline as well.

Comment: This is especially neat if you use `IFS="$(printf '\n\t')"`

Comment: Or just `echo $(<file)` ... using echo is not just neater than using `tr '\n' ' '`, but also better (think `\r\n` line endings). @aggsol you can just say `IFS=$'\n\t'`

Comment: How about without space?

Comment: Works very nicely on Unix systems - but Windows (eg. MSYS2 / Git Bash) doesn't behave the same way - could be other systems that don't work the same way as well.  awk works most reliably for me cross-platform.

Comment: I wanted to use this to grep certain headers from the `curl` response, and apparently headers have a `\r` which messed up the output, so you need to delete the `\r` chars like this: `echo $(curl ... 2>&1 | grep my-headers | tr -d '\r' )`

Answer (score 119):

Piping output to `xargs` will concatenate each line of output to a single line with spaces:

```
grep pattern file | xargs
```

Or any command, eg. `ls | xargs`. The default limit of `xargs` output is ~4096 characters, but can be increased with eg. `xargs -s 8192`.

[grep](/questions/tagged/grep) [xargs](/questions/tagged/xargs)

Comment: `| tr '\n' ' '` was not working for me when called through `php exec` function. It was ignoring tr, and just giving last match from grep. `| xargs` worked.

Comment: This solution also has the advantage that it 'eats' spaces from the input.
+1

Comment: This would remove all double quotes `"`. Not suitable for JSON.

Answer (score 25):

This could be what you want

```
cat file | grep pattern | paste -sd' '
```

As to your edit, I'm not sure what it means, perhaps this?

```
cat file | grep pattern | paste -sd'~' | sed -e 's/~/" "/g'
```

(this assumes that `~` does not occur in `file`)

Comment: @Stephan there was no need to assume that `cat file` will actually be `cat`, or even a file. (I just left that part unchanged as it was irrelevant to the question)

Answer (score 17):

This is an example which produces output separated by commas. You can replace the comma by whatever separator you need.

```
cat <<EOD | xargs | sed 's/ /,/g'
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5
> EOD
```

produces:

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

Answer (score 8):

#### The fastest and easiest ways I know to solve this problem:

When we want to **replace the new line character** `\n` **with the space**:

```
xargs < file
```

`xargs` has own limits on the number of characters per line and the number of all characters combined, but we can increase them. Details can be found by running this command: `xargs --show-limits` and of course in the manual: `man xargs`

When we want to **replace one character with another exactly one character**:

```
tr '\n' ' ' < file
```

When we want to **replace one character with many characters**:

```
tr '\n' '~' < file | sed s/~/many_characters/g
```

First, we replace the newline characters `\n` for tildes `~` (or choose another unique character not present in the text), and then we replace the tilde characters with any other characters (`many_characters`) and we do it for each tilde (flag `g`).

Answer (score 8):

Here is another simple method using `awk`:

```
# cat > file.txt
a
b
c

# cat file.txt | awk '{ printf("%s ", $0) }'
a b c
```

Also, if your file has columns, this gives an easy way to concatenate only certain columns:

```
# cat > cols.txt
a b c
d e f

# cat cols.txt | awk '{ printf("%s ", $2) }'
b e
```

Answer (score 7):

I like the `xargs` solution, but if it's important to not collapse spaces, then one might instead do:

```sh
sed ':b;N;$!bb;s/\n/ /g'
```

That will replace newlines for spaces, without substituting the last line terminator like `tr '\n' ' '` would.

This also allows you to use other joining strings besides a space, like a comma, etc, something that `xargs` cannot do:

```sh
$ seq 1 5 | sed ':b;N;$!bb;s/\n/,/g'
1,2,3,4,5
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the method using [`ex` editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_%28text_editor%29) (part of [Vim](https://www.vim.org/)):

- **J**oin all lines and **p**rint to the standard output:

  ```
  $ ex +%j +%p -scq! file
  ```
- **J**oin all lines in-place (in the file):

  ```
  $ ex +%j -scwq file
  ```

  <sup>Note: This will concatenate all lines inside the file it-self!</sup>

Answer (score 1):

`paste -sd'~'` giving error.

Here's what worked for me on mac using `bash`

```
cat file | grep pattern | paste -d' ' -s -
```

from `man paste` .

```
-d list     Use one or more of the provided characters to replace the newline characters instead of the default tab.  The characters
                 in list are used circularly, i.e., when list is exhausted the first character from list is reused.  This continues until
                 a line from the last input file (in default operation) or the last line in each file (using the -s option) is displayed,
                 at which time paste begins selecting characters from the beginning of list again.

                 The following special characters can also be used in list:

                 \n    newline character
                 \t    tab character
                 \\    backslash character
                 \0    Empty string (not a null character).

                 Any other character preceded by a backslash is equivalent to the character itself.

     -s          Concatenate all of the lines of each separate input file in command line order.  The newline character of every line
                 except the last line in each input file is replaced with the tab character, unless otherwise specified by the -d option.
                 If ‘-’ is specified for one or more of the input files, the standard input is used; standard input is read one line at a time,
```

circularly, for each instance of ‘-’.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to do it is using 'awk' tool which will generate output into one line

```
$ awk ' /pattern/ {print}' ORS=' ' /path/to/file
```

It will merge all lines into one with space delimiter

Comment: You don't need `{print}` since its the default action of awk.

Answer (score -1):

On red hat linux I just use echo :

echo $(cat /some/file/name)

This gives me  all records of a file on just one line.

Comment: This as already been answer in 2015. You are just duplicating [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33540439/9434800). Please read answers before posting your own, specially when the question is 7 years old and there are already 8 answers.