# bash script read line by line then print one line

Tags: bash, shell, mergesort

I have a text file with over 10000 lines and use this code to separate some things:

```
BS=`cat myfile | grep myword`  
cutbs=`cut -d'=' -f2 $BS | sort -u
$cat cutbs  
qwe  
asd  
zxc
```

Now I would like print output of this sort in one line like below:

```
$cat cutbs  
qwe asd zxc
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580144/concatenate-many-lines-of-output-to-one-line

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `paste -s`:

```
cut -d'=' -f2 $BS | sort -u | paste -s
```

Sun OS version:

```
cut -d'=' -f2 $BS | sort -u | paste -s -
```

See:

```
$ cat tubs 
qwe  
asd  
zxc
$ cat tubs | paste -s -
qwe     asd     zxc
```

The items are tab-separated, but you can choose the delimiter. Example with a space:

```
$ cat tubs 
qwe  
asd  
zxc
$ cat tubs | paste -s -d' ' -
qwe asd zxc
```

Beware with your example:

```
cutbs=`cut -d'=' -f2 $BS | sort -u`
```

creates a variable, then you run

```
$cat cutbs
```

which outputs the contents of a file, totally unrelated to `$cutbs`

Comment: "paste -s" does not work properly for me.  my machine: "sunos 10"

Comment: Updated my answer, tested with SunOS 5.10 (Solaris 10 10/09)

Answer (score 0):

You could use sed:

```
$ cat $cutbs | sed -n -e ':start $!{N;s/\n/ /;t start;};P;D;'
```

Or tr:

```
$ cat $cutbs | tr '\n' ' '
```