# git add - flag to add 'both modified:' files only

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

Let me present a scenario - I'm working on a repo, under `my_branch` branch, and I need to merge changes from `other_branch` to my branch.

I ran the command:
`git merge origin/feature/other_branch`

Here is a sample `git status` after running this command:

```
$ git status
On branch feature/my_branch
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/feature/my_branch'.
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")

Changes to be committed:

        modified:   file1
        modified:   file2

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        both modified:   file3
        both modified:   file4

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   file5
        modified:   file6        

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        file7
        file8
```

As you can see, changes to `file1` and `file2` have been accepted from `other_branch` and have been staged for commit.

I've encountered a merge-conflict in `file3` and `file4`, which I've fixed manually on my editor.

I've made some changes to `file5` and `file6`, but I'm not willing to commit those yet...

I've added `file7` and `file8` to the workspace, but I'm not willing to commit those either.

**To add the conflicted files to stage, I need to run:**

```
git add file1
git add file2
```

**Is there some flag** in `git add`, using which I can only the files in `both modified` state, whilst ignoring modified and unstaged files ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know of this option, but you can always open the files in conflict and look at the merge markers.

Comment: Have you tried looking in the [git documentation] (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) for such a flag?

Comment: No, currently there is no such "special add". You should force your self not doing "developent" while merging is still in progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`git add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) itself has no such flag.

But it can take as parameters a list of files.
And you can [list unmerged files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10874862/6309):

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U
```

So, something like this could work ([using this to bring all files in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15580184/6309)):

```
git add $(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U | xargs)
```