# unix sql run a script in on row

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, sqlplus

I have to execute a script in just on row.

Here is my script (simplified version) `tt.sh`:

```
result=`sqlplus -s / as sysdba <<EOSQL
set heading off feed off termout off pages 0 lines 150 serveroutput on
select 1 from dual;
EOSQL`
if [ $result = '1' ] ; then echo 'OK'; else echo 'KO'; fi;
```

When i run the the script, it works:

```
./tt.sh
OK
```

Is there a possibility  to put the 5 lines of tt.sh in one line?

Thank in advance

Comment: Looks like this is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/): please, describe what you want to achieve and why you want to put everything in one line. Or check [this question about similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580144/how-to-concatenate-multiple-lines-of-output-to-one-line): but do it backwards, replace something with newline (it doesn't matter what is the separator).

Comment: Hello, Thank for your answer. This is not an XY problem. I 'm forced to run this stupid program in one raw. So please help me if you can.

Comment: Might still well be an XY problem. The real problem seems to be that you have to use only one r**o**w (or think so). Maybe you should work on that or tell us the reasons so we can help.

Comment: I need to insert this code into a screen. Scripts played in this screen must absolutely be on one line. This is really not an XY problem :)

Comment: What does "insert this code into a screen" mean?

Comment: Listen,
In my company, I have to run this script in this tool. It does not allow me to go to the line. So help me if you can. thanks in advance.

Comment: thank for your response: syntax error ar line ; 'then' unexpected U have errors on brackets

Comment: If for whatever reason you are limited to one line, create a script with multiple lines, give execute permission, invoke the script, it would be only one line

Answer (score 0):

If there is a problem '`ORA-`' will occur.

```
sqlplus -L -S / as sysdba < /dev/null |grep 'ORA-'; if [[ $$? == 1 ]]; then echo 'KO'; else echo 'OK'; fi
```

Best of luck!