# Linux Grep Command - Extract multiple texts between strings

Tags: grep, substring

**Context;**

After running the following command on my server:

> zgrep "ResCode-5005" /loggers1/PCRF*/*_01_03_2022* > analisis.txt

I get a text file with thousands of lines like this example:

> loggers1/PCRF1_17868/PCRF12_01_03_2022_00_15_39.log:[C]|01-03-2022:00:18:20:183401|140404464875264|TRACKING: CCR processing Compleated for SubId-5281181XXXXX, REQNO-1, REQTYPE-3,
> SId-mscp01.herpgwXX.epc.mncXXX.mccXXX.XXXXX.org;25b8510c;621dbaab;3341100102036XX-27cf0XXX,
> RATTYPE-1004, ResCode-5005 |processCCR|ProcessingUnit.cpp|423

(X represents incrementing numbers)

**Problem:**

The output is filled with unnecessary data. The only string portions I need are the MSISDN,IMSI comma separated for each line, like this:

5281181XXXXX,3341100102036XX

**Steps I tried**

> zgrep "ResCode-5005" /loggers1/PCRF*/*_01_03_2022*| grep -o -P
> '(?<=SubId-).*?(?=, REQ)' > analisis1.txt

This gave me the first part of the solution

> 5281181XXXXX

However, when I tried to get the second string located between '334110' and "-"

> zgrep "ResCode-5005" /loggers1/PCRF*/*_01_03_2022*| grep -o -P
> '(?<=SubId-).*?(?=, REQ)' | grep -o -P '(?<=334110).*?(?=-)' >
> analisis1.txt

it doesn't work.

Any input will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get `5281181XXXXX` or `the second string located between '334110' and "-"` you can use a pattern like:

```
\b(?:SubId-|334110)\K[^,\s-]+
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(?:` Non capture group to match as a whole

  - `SubId-` Match literally
  - `|` Or
  - `334110` Match literally
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `[^,\s-]+` Match 1+ occurrences of any char except a whitespace char `,` or `-`

See the matches in this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/StztMs/1).

That will match:

```
5281181XXXXX
0102036XX
```

The command could look like

```
zgrep "ResCode-5005" /loggers1/PCRF*/_01_03_2022 | grep -oP '\b(?:SubId-|334110)\K[^,\s-]+' > analisis1.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer. I wonder how could I concatenate the output of the regex to get both the 5281181XXXXX and 3341100102036XX portions in one line, comma separated. I saw examples using scripts, but maybe there is a more elegant way inside the regex black magic book.

Comment: @FelipeLaRotta From what I can see for example on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580144/how-to-concatenate-multiple-lines-of-output-to-one-line) you could pipe the output to `| tr '\n' ','` so I think the command would be `zgrep "ResCode-5005" /loggers1/PCRF*/_01_03_2022 | grep -oP '\b(?:SubId-|334110)\K[^,\s-]+' | tr '\n' ',' > analisis1.txt` Or you can pipe it to awk `| awk '{print}' ORS=', '`