# Reading individual rows from a file and using values in another script

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have a file (x.txt) with a single column containing a hundred values.

```
228.71
245.58
253.71
482.72
616.73
756.74
834.72
858.62
934.61
944.60        
....
```

I want to input each of these values to an existing script I have such that my command on the terminal is:

```
script_name 228.71 245.58 253.71........... and so on.
```

I am trying to create a bash script such that each row is read automatically from the file and taken into the script. I have been trying this for a while now but could not get a solution.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: please update the question with your coding attempts and the (wrong) output generated by your code

Comment: are you looking to store each value from the .txt file inside a list?

Comment: please confirm the structure of your input file ... one line with 100 values *or* 100 lines with one value per line?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580144/how-to-concatenate-multiple-lines-of-output-to-one-line) could be of use

Answer (score 0):

You could read the text file line by line into a list, stripping any newlines on the way. The `subprocess.call` call takes a list of the command to run plus any arguments. So create a new list with the values just read and the name of the command.

```
import sys
import subprocess

values = [line.strip() for line in open("x.txt")]
subprocess.call(["script_name"] + values)
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure Bash, you could use `mapfile`/`readarray` to have an array populated with each line of input file.

For example:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
CMDNAME="${0##*/}"
mapfile -t data < x.txt
printf "%s %s\n" "$CMDNAME" "${data[*]}"
```

Output with script named `foo.sh` :

```
$ ./foo.sh
foo.sh 228.71 245.58 253.71 482.72 616.73 756.74 834.72 858.62 934.61 944.60
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a standard utility for this.

```
$ cat x.txt | xargs script_name
```

Consult the [man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) for details.
Possibly you'd like to adjust the `-n` value.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk, you can concatenate them to a single line by making ORS=" "

```
awk 'BEGIN {ORS=" "} { print } ' x.txt
```

Copy the output to a variable and pass it to the script_name