# Transforming a list of files names to concatenated with space

Tags: git, shell

I can do `git diff --name-only HEAD develop` which gives a list of file names like this:

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
```

How can I transform this to be separated by space like this:

```
a.txt b.txt c.txt
```

Comment: Side note: beware of Windows (and occasionally MacOS) files with names like `files for bob.rar`.  Some systems also allow newlines in file names, but spaces in file names are very common these days.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join multiple lines of file names into one with custom delimiter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764051/how-to-join-multiple-lines-of-file-names-into-one-with-custom-delimiter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use can use tr command to replace `newline` with `space`

```
echo file | tr '\n' ' '
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo "a.txt
b.txt
c.txt" | paste -s -d ' '
a.txt b.txt c.txt
$
```

`paste` it serially(`-s`) with delimiter `-d` as space

or use translate `tr` command like this:

```
$ echo "a.txt
b.txt
c.txt" | tr '\n' ' '
a.txt b.txt c.txt
```