# Exclude submodule of a submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have git repo where I link some of my dependencies using git submodules inside `extern/` dir. Say I have a dependency `A` as a submodule, located at `extern/A`. Now `A` itself has some dependencies as git submodules. In `A`'s repo, that is, eg. `A/test/data/X`.

Now when I clone my repo, and run `git submodule update --init --recursive`, in order to build it on a CI server, or w'ever, I'd like the above command to ignore `exter/A/test/data/X`, because it's like 1G of data that I don't want.

My other dependencies however, have some useful submodules, so I can't just skip `--recursive`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exclude a specific git submodule from update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52179463/how-to-exclude-a-specific-git-submodule-from-update)

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari it is for sure not a duplicate for that one. It is a valid question

Comment: @Zatarra, Updated the answer

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari your update it is still not valid for a submodule of a submodule (nested)

Comment: @Zatarra, I have tested it on nested submodules, it works for me

Comment: @zatarra why is it "not valid" ?

Comment: Just try to apply that on https://github.com/MISP/MISP.git by ignoring tests/viper-test-files submodule of PyMISP submodule . For me it didn't work

Comment: @Zatarra, since the submodule is located in a directory called tests, the submodule name in this case would be "tests/viper-test-files", then the command will be ```git -c submodule."tests/viper-test-files".update=none submodule update --init --recursive```

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari I know, but have you tried it? I'll make it as short as possible for you in the next comment and you will still see the files are there, when they shouldn't

Comment: god@supermachine:~/git-test$ git clone https://github.com/MISP/MISP.git > /dev/null 2>&1
god@supermachine:~/git-test$ ls
MISP
god@supermachine:~/git-test$ cd MISP/
god@supermachine:~/git-test/MISP$ git -c submodule."tests/viper-test-files".update=none submodule update --init --recursive > /dev/null 2>&1
god@supermachine:~/git-test/MISP$ ls PyMISP/tests/viper-test-files/
README.md  test_files
god@supermachine:~/git-test/MISP$

Comment: There was a version problem which got fixed in later updates (it seems that I was using a very old one)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `submodule.<name>.update` config variable to set which submodule should be updated as mentioned here
[How to exclude a specific git submodule from update?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52179463/10155936).

If you want to exclude the submodule X in A, then you can use the following command:

```
git -c submodule."X".update=none submodule update --init --recursive
```

**Note:** This assumes that the submodule X in repo A (*which is a submodule of extern*) is unique across the whole repo extern (*including all its submodules, and their submodules and so on...*) If X is not unique, then all submodules named X will be skipped in repo extern.

---

You can skip the submodules during the cloning process, using the following command:

```
$ git -c submodule."X".update=none clone --recurse-submodules <repository>
```

---

If the submodule is located in a directory under the repository, then the relative path with respect to its repository should be included in the submodule name. To avoid any confusion, you can get the submodule name from the `.gitmodules` file in the repository.

Consider the following example `.gitmodules` file,

```
[submodule "path/to/submodule_X"]
    path = path/to/submodule_X
    url = https://github.com/<user>/<repo>
[submodule "Y"]
    path = Y
    url = https://github.com/<user>/<repo>
```

If you want to skip submodule X, then replace `<name>` in `submodule.<name>.update` with this `"path/to/submodule_X"`. The same applies to nested submodules.

Comment: I don't know in which version they did the patch, but it was not working on 2.7.4, but it worked on 2.17.2. Thanks a lot for your time on this issue

Answer (score 1):

Here is another syntax

```
git clone --recurse-submodules=':(exclude)**/unwanted_submodule_pathspec:
```

using the optional [pathspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary) argument of [--recurse-submodules[=<pathspec>]](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone).