# .gitmodules options to ignore a submodule in a submodule

Tags: git, configuration, git-submodules

I have a git repository with a hierarchy of submodules similar to this:

```sh
TopLevelRepo
+- .gitmodules # this is where I want the configuration
+- externals
   +- RepoA # this is a 3rd party repository and I cannot modify it
   |  +- externals
   |     +- RepoB # this repository is not necessary and is very large
   |     +- RepoC # this repository is required
   +- RepoD
   +- dozens more repositories
```

The way I clone the repository is one of these:

```sh
git clone --recursive https://github.com/TopLevelRepo TopLevelRepo
# or
git clone https://github.com/TopLevelRepo TopLevelRepo
cd TopLevelRepo
git submodules update --init --recursive
```

Is there an option that I can add to .gitmodules (or any other file that is checked into the repository) that would allow me to skip (avoid cloning) the RepoB, but keep the RepoC?

I have already found this:
[Exclude submodule of a submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56745097/exclude-submodule-of-a-submodule)
which would apparently do what I want, but I need it to be stored in the top level repository.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, the top-level superproject cannot manage subsubmodules, only the immediate parent can. Try something like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/TopLevelRepo TopLevelRepo
cd TopLevelRepo
git submodules update --init RepoA
cd RepoA
git config submodule.RepoB.update none
cd ../.. # back to TopLevelRepo
git submodules update --init --recursive
```

Comment: Or `git -C RepoA config submodule.RepoB.update none`.