# How do i specify to download some submodules in .gitsubmodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

There are too many submodule in .gitsubmodule, and downloading all of them will take a lot of time. How can I choose to download only the modules I need.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to configure the [`update` setting to `none`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52185169/6309) for the submodules you *don't* want to update.
But that would only affect the `git submodule update` command.

A better option would be to declare those submodules not active.
See ["ACTIVE SUBMODULES"](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitsubmodules#_active_submodules)

```
[submodule]
  active = b*
  active = :(exclude) baz
```

> In here all submodules except `baz` (`foo`, `bar`, `bob`) are active.
> `foo` due to its own active flag and all the others due to the submodule active pathspec, which specifies that any submodule starting with `b` except `baz` are also active, regardless of the presence of the `.url` field.

That is, however, a local option, since the repository Git configuration is not  itself versioned.

Comment: Note however that setting a submodule as inactive is not something you can do in `.gitmodules`, so it would not prevent `git clone --recurse-submodules` from cloning them.

Comment: Also, as of Git 2.33 `git checkout` never clones nor fetches submodules (not sure what you meant by "download").

Comment: @philb Good point. I have edit my answer to include that caveat.