# Pass configuration parameter(s) to a git command via xargs util

Tags: git, xargs

I am trying build a command using `xargs` to  pass configuration parameters : `user.name` and `user.email` to `git commit`.

Command to be built by `xargs` :

```
git -c user.name=abc -c user.email=abc@mail.com commit
```

What I have tried :

```
echo "-c user.name=abc -c user.email=abc@mail.com" | xargs -I % git % commit
```

However, `git` returns this :

> unknown option: -c user.name=abc -c user.email=abc@mail.com

Even with `xargs` verbose, the command works fine.

```
echo "-c user.name=abc -c user.email=abc@mail.com" | xargs -tI % git % commit
```

This prints the command to be executed `git -c user.name=abc -c user.email=abc@mail.com commit` which works when copy-pasted to the terminal.

Note that the configuration parameters are separated by whitespaces.

[Some context for what exactly I am trying to do by passing configuration parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59247234/10155936)

Comment: Which OS? `-J` instead of `-I` solves it for OS X. (The problem is that `-I %` replaces `%` with the line _as one parameter_ (as if you wrote `git "-c user.name=abc -c user.email=abc@mail.com" commit`). On Linux (whose `xargs` doesn't support `-J`) you can do it using a subshell: `xargs -I % bash -c "git % commit"`

Comment: @Amadan, I have tried it on both linux shell and git-bash for windows. Shouldn't verbose for ```xargs``` show this ```git "-c user.name=abc -c user.email=abc@mail.com" commit``` instead of this ```git -c user.name=abc -c user.email=abc@mail.com commit``` ? (based on the problem described for ```-I```)

Comment: No. I said "as if". `xargs` doesn't actually construct quotes; it executes the function using a C function similar to this: `execl("git", "-c user.name=abc -c user.emal=abc@mail.com", "commit")`, where it executes the `git` command with two arguments. Splitting the command line by spaces (or taking a quoted string as one) is shell's job, but there is no shell involved here. The verbose just prints all the arguments connected with a space, just like echo would do; you can't distinguish how parameters are split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per comments, `xargs` was replacing the single parameter `%` with a single parameter `-c user.name=abc -c user.email=abc@mail.com`; the resultant command

```
git -c user.name=abc -c user.email=abc@mail.com commit
```

has two parameters, the first of which is `-c user.name=abc -c user.email=abc@mail.com`, clearly an invalid option.

The most portable way to solve it that I can think of is to have a shell re-interpret the line:

```
echo "-c user.name=abc -c user.email=abc@mail.com" | xargs -I % bash -c "git % commit"
```

This way, `xargs` will execute `bash` with two parameters: `-c` and `git -c user.name=abc -c user.email=abc@mail.com commit`. `bash -c command` executes that command, which includes full command line parsing that `bash` normally performs. This will result in `bash` executing `git` with five parameters: `-c`, `user.name=abc`, `-c`, `user.email=abc@mail.com` and `commit`.

Comment: As per [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_alternatives.html#DIFFERENCES-BETWEEN-xargs-AND-GNU-Parallel), ```If you use a replace string in xargs (-I) you can not force xargs to use more than one argument.```

Comment: I wanted to confirm with the docs too, +1 and accepted the answer :)