# How do I switch between different Kubernetes contexts described in distinct kubeconfig yaml files fast?

Tags: kubectl, context-switch, kubeconfig

I need to access several Kubernetes clusters. For each of them, I got a kubeconfig yaml file, e.g. `kubeconfig-cluster1.yaml` and `kubeconfig-cluster2.yaml`.

How can I easily switch between these configurations? I mean, without setting the `KUBECONFIG` environment variable manually to one of these files?

Comment: General KUBECONFIG tips by the developer of the kubectx utility: https://medium.com/@ahmetb/mastering-kubeconfig-4e447aa32c75

Comment: Also have a look at the direnv tool which lets you automatically set environment variables based on the directory tree you’re in: https://direnv.net

Answer (score 1):

You can declare all contexts in the [KUBECONFIG environment variable](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/#the-kubeconfig-environment-variable):

> The KUBECONFIG environment variable holds a list of kubeconfig files. For Linux and Mac, the list is colon-delimited. For Windows, the list is semicolon-delimited.

To autodetect the contexts based on the kubeconfig files, assuming they're all located in the `~/.kube` folder, and assign them as a colon-separated list to the `KUBECONFIG` environment variable, you could add a script to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`:

```
# Autodetect kubeconfig files to enable switching between them with kubectx
export KUBECONFIG=`ls -1 ~/.kube/kubeconfig-* | paste -sd ":" -`
```

Then, to switch between these kubectl contexts (with autocomplete!), have a look at the [kubectx](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx) utility. 
The [kubectx README page](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx) contains installation instructions.

```
$ kubectx cluster1
Switched to context "cluster1".
$ kubectx cluster2
Switched to context "cluster2".
```

Comment: Credits for the file name concatenation go to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6539865/4769344

Answer (score 0):

I also had multiple kubernetes cluster to manage. I wrote a script to switch kubeconfig and namespace easily. Hope it can help you.

```
. k-use -k <kubeconfig> -n <namespace>
```

https://github.com/kingonion/k-use