# convert data of text file into JSON array in bash

Tags: arrays, json, bash, shell

I want output in the below JSON array format with command on linux/bash platform . Can anybody help

data in text file

```
test:test
test1:test1
test4:test4
```

**Expecting output:**

```
{array : 
   [
     {test:test},
     {test1:test1}, 
     {test4:test4}
   ]
}
```

Comment: How was this data generated?

Comment: Note that `”` is not `"`. Just read the input line by line with `:` as separator and output them in the formar `{"something":"something"}` then joni the lines with comma. [How to read a file line by line](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) [How to join lines with delimeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764051/how-to-join-multiple-lines-of-file-names-into-one-with-custom-delimiter)

Comment: Your output is not valid JSON...

Comment: I have made changes in the question. Please check if that makes more sense

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Your expected output is still not valid JSON. If you want something  JSON-like but not, don't call it JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `jq` command line JSON parser:

```
<file jq -Rs '{array:split("\n")|map(split(":")|{(.[0]):.[1]}?)}'
{
  "array": [
    {
      "test": "test"
    },
    {
      "test1": "test1"
    },
    {
      "test4": "test4"
    }
  ]
}
```

The options `Rs` let `jq` read the whole file as one string.

The script `split`s this string into pieces in order to have the expected format.

Comment: Can I append new pair (Key/value) to the existing array                                                    
 "test5": "test5"       {
  "array": [
    {
      "test": "test"
    },
    {
      "test1": "test1"
    },
    {
      "test4": "test4"
    },
    {
      "test5”: "test5”
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want actual JSON output:

```
$ jq -nR '{array: (reduce inputs as $line ([]; . + [$line | split(":") | {(.[0]):.[1]}]))}' input.txt 
{
  "array": [
    {
      "test": "test"
    },
    {
      "test1": "test1"
    },
    {
      "test4": "test4"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a JSON works best with a dedicated JSON tool that can also make sense of raw text.
[`xidel`](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) is such a tool.

**XPath:**

```
xidel -s input.txt -e '{"array":x:lines($raw) ! {substring-before(.,":"):substring-after(.,":")}}'
```

(`x:lines($raw)` is a shorthand for `tokenize($raw,'\r\n?|\n')`, which creates a sequence of all lines.)

**XQuery:**

```
xidel -s input.txt --xquery '{"array":for $x in x:lines($raw) let $a:=tokenize($x,":") return {$a[1]:$a[2]}}'
```

See also [this](http://www.videlibri.de/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&data=test%3Atest%0D%0Atest1%3Atest1%0D%0Atest4%3Atest4&extract=%7B%0D%0A%20%20%22array%22%3Ax%3Alines(%24raw)%20!%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20substring-before(.%2C%22%3A%22)%3Asubstring-after(.%2C%22%3A%22)%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%2C%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%22array%22%3Afor%20%24x%20in%20x%3Alines(%24raw)%20let%20%24a%3A%3Dtokenize(%24x%2C%22%3A%22)%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%24a[1]%3A%24a[2]%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D&extract-kind=xquery3.0&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&input-format=auto&dot-notation=unambiguous) Xidel online tester.