# How to replace a new line with special characters ( ',' ) using sed command

Tags: shell, sed, special-characters

New line should be replaced with `','` please ignore the brackets only the special characters inside it

I have already tried two commands

`sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\','/g' test.txt` - This command replaces the new line with , but the quotes are not coming

`sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\'\,\'/g' test.txt` - I tried giving escape character for all the three Special characters but this time terminal asks me for next line input i.e ( > )

Example below :

aaa

bbb

ccc

'aaa','bbb','ccc'

Comment: But why specifically `sed`? You want to join lines with a comma? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764051/how-to-join-multiple-lines-of-file-names-into-one-with-custom-delimiter ? Or you want to join lines with 3 characters, apostrophe, comma and another apostrophe?

Comment: Yes I want to join lines with 3 characters as you said

Comment: The problem is I'm having those two single quotes, if it is just the comma its easy as the link you shared

Comment: `sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/'\',\''/g'`

Comment: @KamilCuk Thank you it worked