# how to print An array on the same line

Tags: bash, jenkins-pipeline, bash-completion

I am reading a file which contains the following config as an array:

```
$ cat ./FILENAME
*.one.dev.arr.name.com
*.one.dev.brr.name.com
*.one.dev.sic.name.com
*.one.dev.sid.name.com
*.one.dev.xyz.name.com
*.one.dev.yza.name.com
```

The array is read
`IFS='$\n' read -d '' -r -a FILENAME < ./FILENAME`

I need the format to be of the following format:

```
'{*.one.dev.arr.name.com,*.one.dev.brr.name.com,*.one.dev.sic.name.com,*.one.dev.sid.name.com,*.one.dev.xyz.name.com,*.one.dev.yza.name.com}'
```

I've tried using printf, the tricky part is the wildcard(*) at the start of the name.

Comment: Do you _need_ an array? Why use an array at all, just https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764051/how-to-join-multiple-lines-of-file-names-into-one-with-custom-delimiter

Comment: please update the question with the `printf` command(s) you've tried and the (wrong) output generated by said command(s)

Comment: I don't think the `IFS/read` command is populating the `FILENAME[]` array properly; run `typeset -p FILENAME` to see the contents of the array; consider using `mapfile -t FILENAME < FILENAME` for loading the `FILENAME[]` array; might also want to rethink the name of the file and/or the array, as is the use of `FILENAME` for both could be a bit confusing for someone else having to maintain this script

Answer (score 1):

Just output what you want to output - `{` and `}` and join lines with `,`:

```
echo "{$(paste -sd, FILENAME)}"
```

If you want with an array, you can just:

```
echo "{$(IFS=, ; echo "${array[*]}")}"
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I get an output of }*.one.dev.arr.name.com and only the one

Comment: You file has dos line endings. Remove them. Reesearch `dos2unix`.