# Removing newlines in a txt file

Tags: bash, shell

I have a txt file in a format like this:

```
test1
test2
test3
```

How can I bring it into a format like this using bash?

`test1,test2,test3`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that “using Bash” means “without any external processes”:

```sh
if IFS= read -r line; then
  printf '%s' "$line"
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf ',%s' "$line"
  done
  echo
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

[Old answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764051/how-to-join-multiple-lines-of-file-names-into-one-with-custom-delimiter)

TL;DR:

```sh
cat "export.txt" | paste -sd ","
```

Comment: The example is a UUOC.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek, what is a UUOC? Please avoid ambiguous or uncommon acronyms.

Comment: Useless use of `cat`: use `paste -sd "," < export.txt` if you want to use `export.txt` as standard input.

Comment: If you are going to link to another answer, you should just vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @Chris UUOC is neither ambiguous nor uncommon. (I wish it was uncommon, but sadly that’s not the case.)

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek, whether you believe it's common or not, clarity is important. "Useless use of cat" and an example (as chepner wrote) is much more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Another pure `bash` implementation that avoids explicit loops:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file2csv() {
    local -a lines
    readarray -t lines <"$1"
    local IFS=,
    printf "%s\n" "${lines[*]}"
}

file2csv input.txt
```

Comment: Dealing with commas or quotes in the file will of course require a more robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk. If the file name is test.txt then

```
awk '{print $1}' ORS=',' test.txt | awk '{print substr($1, 1, length($1)-1)}'
```

The first awk commad joins the three lines with comma (test1,test2,test3,).
The second awk command just deletes the last comma from the string.

Answer (score 0):

Use tool 'tr' (translate) and sed to remove last comma:

```
tr '\n' , < "$source_file" | sed 's/,$//'
```

If you want to save the output into a variable:

```
var="$( tr '\n' , < "$source_file" | sed 's/,$//' )"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed:

```
$ sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g' file
```

Output:

```
test1,test2,test3
```

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252191/4162356) is where I originally picked it up.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a terminating newline:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", sep, $0; sep=","}' file
test1,test2,test3
```

or if you do:

```
awk '{printf "%s%s", sep, $0; sep=","} END{print ""}' file
test1,test2,test3
```

Answer (score 0):

Another loopless pure Bash solution:

```
contents=$(< input.txt)
printf '%s\n' "${contents//$'\n'/,}"
```

- `contents=$(< input.txt)` is equivalent to `contents=$(cat input.txt)`.  It puts the contents of the `input.txt` file (with trailing newlines automatically removed) into the variable `contents`.
- `"${contents//$'\n'/,}"` replaces all occurrences of the newline character (`$'\n'`) in `contents` with the comma character.  See [Parameter expansion [Bash Hackers Wiki]](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).
- See the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812) for an explanation of why `printf '%s\n'` is used instead of `echo`.