# Bash: Converting string with new lines to string with unique values with commas, inline

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am working with some bash script and would need your help :) The result that I want: `V04.01, V04.02` - one string, no new lines, unique values, commas. Only name prefixes (all before __), only for sql files.

**The original diff command and its results:**

`git diff --name-only 123132132213 origin/dev`

**gives:**

```
.abc.yml
abc/test.xml
aaa/V04.01__SampleInsert.sql
bbb/V04.01__SampleInsert.sql
abc/efg/V04.02__SampleUpdate.sql
```

**The result that I want:** `V04.01, V04.02`

**My script which is not working:**

`git diff --name-only 12313123123132 origin/dev | grep '.sql' | rev | cut -d"/" -f1 | rev | awk '{sub(/__.*/,x)}1'`

**The result is:**

```
V04.01
V04.01
V04.02
```

Thanks in advance if anyone has some idea how to do that inline.

Comment: You also don't need `grep`, `rev`, or `cut` when you're using `awk` - show us the output of `git diff --name-only 12313123123132 origin/dev` so we can help you with that part too.

Comment: Given that you don't need grep, rev, or cut, my guess is you don't need a comma separated string or an array.  What is your end goal?

Comment: The result that I want: V04.01, V04.02 - one string, no new lines, unique values, commas.  Only name prefixes (all before __), only for sql files.

Comment: For getting unique values, you could pipe your text file into `sort -u`. For getting the commas as separator, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764051/how-to-join-multiple-lines-of-filenames-into-one-with-custom-delimiter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `cat file` in place of your `git` command which I don't have:

```
$ cat file | awk -F'/' '/\.sql$/{ sub(/__.*/,"",$NF); if ( !seen[$NF]++ ) printf "%s%s", sep, $NF; sep=", " }'
V04.01, V04.02
```

I know you said you don't want any newlines but that makes the output not a valid text file so if you do want a terminating newline just add `END{print ""}` to the end of the awk script.

Comment: Wow, that works perfectly, I am marking it as best answer for me :) Many thanks, best wishes :)

Answer (score 1):

Here a possibile solution:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

YOUR_COMMAND_OUTPUT=$(cat << EOF
V04.01
V04.01
V04.02
EOF
)

UNIQUE_LINES=$(echo "${YOUR_COMMAND_OUTPUT}" | sort | uniq)
JOINED_STRING=$(echo ${UNIQUE_LINES} | sed "s/ /, /g")

echo ${JOINED_STRING}
```

The output is:

```
V04.01, V04.02
```

**PS:** in order to reproduce your script output I introduced the `YOUR_COMMAND_OUTPUT` instruction whoch you have to replace with your real script.

Comment: Be sure to quote your variables to avoid cryptic and dangerous errors, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes. Also see [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization) for when to capitalize variable names.

Comment: This works too but only when I added sort before uniq.

Comment: You are right, I edit it.